# How do I get the rows in specific column up together correctly in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

How do you add up all the rows in a specific column, if you look at the picture I have provided below.

What I have circled in blue does add up correctly with what I have circled in red.

[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Pp2z.png)

What I have circled in blue is using this expression: =Round(Fields!Average_Kilometers.Value, 2)

What I have circled in red is using this expression: =Round(Sum(Fields!Average_Kilometers.Value), 2)

I guess what I am trying to do make the number at the bottom right corner of my table add up correctly.

As Requested my DataSet I am using

```
Select ALLOCATED_STATE, ODO_READING,
From PSA_FleetMaster as A
left outer JOIN XMPRO_PSA_STAGING..PSA_FleetOdometerReadings as B
on A.Unique_ID = B.FLEET_UNIQUE_ID
WHERE B.Unique_ID is not NULL
AND B.Date_Added between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Number_Days =DateDiff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value, Parameters!EndDate.Value)

Average_Kilometers =Fields!ODO_READING.Value / Fields!Number_Days.Value

Edit: As requested I have added the full table that is generated with the above fields I hid some of the columns so that users don't see it all and get confused.

[More Information Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUxho.png)

Thanks All,

Jack

Comment: I suspect you have more than 1 row per division based on what you are seeing, can you edit your question and post a sample of your dataset output. I think I know what the problem is but I don't want to spend time writing an answer and explanation if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi Alan I have put it in there for you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant a sample of the data that is returned from that query in your dataset. If there is more than a single row per division then the answer will be slightly different

Comment: HI Alan, I have unhidden the other two columns in the report and attached an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you do not have any row groups and the data returned from your dataset is exactly as you show in the results. Then you should just be able to do this

```
=SUM(Fields!ODO_READING.Value / Fields!Number_Days.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Replace 'DataSet1' with the name of your actual dataset. It must be enclosed in double quotes and is case sensitive.

The above simple says "for each row in the dataset called "DataSet", do the calculation, then sum the results.